# executing something when user cancels out of prompt()

Tags: javascript

```js
// Sending prompt to the User
let username = prompt("Enter username")

// If the user entered any thing in the prompt
if (username = true) {
  console.log("Welcome " + username)
}

// If the user cancelled the prompt
else {
  console.log("Please enter a username")
}
```

I'm trying to execute something when the user clicks cancel on `prompt()`

Comment: It returns `null` when the user cancels.

Comment: `=` should be `==` in the `if` condition. It will never be equal to `true`. Use `if (username != null)`

Comment: You can also use `if (username)`. Then you'll tell them that they need to enter a username if they leave it blank.

Comment: Did you do any research first? The documentation and all tutorials should explain this.

Comment: @Barmar Assigning a value to a variable returns the value, that's why the `else` is never called because it always returns `true` (b = "foo" returns "foo"). The answer is what you said of course.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt):

> When the user clicks the OK button, text entered in the input field is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned. If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null.

Thus, you should check for `null`. If the value is not `null`, you can use it.

```js
let username = prompt("Enter username");
if (username === null) {
    // prompt cancelled
} else {
    // use the value of username
}
```

If you want to ensure that the input is not blank (all whitespace), you can trim it:

```js
if (!username?.trim()) {
    // prompt cancelled, or the input was blank
} else {
    // use username
}
```